# How do I run my application on https://localhost instead of of https://localhos:4200

Tags: angular, ssl, https, oauth-2.0

I want to run my angular application on https://localhost instead of https://localhost:4200,my redirect uri for oauth doesn't contain port,how do I achieve this,what does that exactly mean? I have been looking for resources.

Comment: Run it in port 80: `ng serve --port 80`

Comment: @OscarLudick it says permission denied :: 1:80

Comment: `Permission denied` might indicate that the port is already in use.

Comment: Ran it on 443 ,thanks so much for the hint @OscarLudick  How does this bind actually, any reference to go through??

Comment: You are right i did not see the https. When you use ssl it uses the port 443 as the default https protocol, so you do not need to specify it in the URL .